# Apigility child routes not getting parent parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm attempting to write a child route for an Apigility Service, and everything routes fine until it comes time to render the `_self` link..

```
GET http://host/api/service/parameter/gui/page

{
    "status": 500,
    "title": "Unexpected error",
    "describedBy": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
    "detail": "Missing parameter \"parameter\"",
    "details": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "Missing parameter \"parameter\"",
        "trace": "#0 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php(313): Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\Segment->buildPath(Array, Array, true, true, Array)\n#1 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php(409): Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\Segment->buildPath(Array, Array, false, true, Array)\n#2 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Part.php(197): Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\Segment->assemble(Array, Array)\n#3 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php(351): Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\Part->assemble(Array, Array)\n#4 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Url.php(100): Zend\\Mvc\\Router\\Http\\TreeRouteStack->assemble(Array, Array)\n#5 [internal function]: Zend\\View\\Helper\\Url->__invoke('parent.rest.s...', Array, Array, true)\n#6 /vagrant/vendor/zfcampus/zf-hal/src/Plugin/Hal.php(610): call_user_func(Object(Zend\\View\\Helper\\Url), 'parent.rest.s...', Array, Array, true)\n#7 /vagrant/vendor/zfcampus/zf-hal/src/Plugin/Hal.php(634): ZF\\Hal\\Plugin\\Hal->fromLink(Object(ZF\\Hal\\Link\\Link))\n#8 /vagrant/vendor/zfcampus/zf-hal/src/Plugin/Hal.php(667): ZF\\Hal\\Plugin\\Hal->fromLinkCollection(Object(ZF\\Hal\\Link\\LinkCollection))\n#9 /vagrant/vendor/zfcampus/zf-hal/src/Plugin/Hal.php(525): ZF\\Hal\\Plugin\\Hal->fromResource(Object(ZF\\Hal\\Entity))\n#10 /vagrant/vendor/zfcampus/zf-hal/src/View/HalJsonRenderer.php(117): ZF\\Hal\\Plugin\\Hal->renderEntity(Object(ZF\\Hal\\Entity))\n#11 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205): ZF\\Hal\\View\\HalJsonRenderer->render(Object(ZF\\Hal\\View\\HalJsonModel))\n#12 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\\View\\View->render(Object(ZF\\Hal\\View\\HalJsonModel))\n#13 [internal function]: Zend\\Mvc\\View\\Http\\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent))\n#14 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent))\n#15 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent), Array)\n#16 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(352): Zend\\EventManager\\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent))\n#17 /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(327): Zend\\Mvc\\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\\Mvc\\MvcEvent))\n#18 /vagrant/public/index.php(38): Zend\\Mvc\\Application->run()\n#19 {main}"
    }
}
```

Looking at the ZF2 MVC documentation, I kind of realize I need to setup a metadata_map entry for my parameter.. but no examples for Apigility exist.  I've read hard coding didn't work, even so, this `parameter` is dynamic and it's unclear how to do that call properly from `module.config.php`

```
'zf-hal' => array(
    'metadata_map' => array(
        'Parent\\V1\\Rest\\Service\\ServiceEntity' => array(
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'parameter',
            'route_name' => 'parent.rest.service',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'parameter',
            'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ObjectProperty',
        ),
        'Parent\\V1\\Rest\\Service\\ServiceCollection' => array(
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'parameter',
            'route_name' => 'parent.rest.service',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'parameter',
            'is_collection' => true,
        ),
        'Parent\\V1\\Rest\\Gui\\GuiEntity' => array(
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'page',
            'route_name' => 'parent.rest.service/gui',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'gui_page',
            'route_params' => array('parameter'),   #<------- unknown setting area, needs to get the parent route identifier somehow...
            'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ObjectProperty',
        ),
        'Parent\\V1\\Rest\\Gui\\GuiCollection' => array(
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'page',
            'route_name' => 'parent.rest.service/gui',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'gui_page',
            'route_params' => array('parameter'),
            'is_collection' => true,
        ),
    ),
),
```

edit : adding the router configuration

```
 'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'parent.rest.service' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/api/service[/:parameter]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Parent\\V1\\Rest\\Service\\Controller',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'gui' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/gui[/:page]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Parent\\V1\\Rest\\Gui\\Controller',
                            ),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Can you show please show some details on your router configuration?

Comment: @Wilt thank you for looking, I've edited to add the router config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some experience with Apigility, but not with your kind of configuration.
As far as I know it indeed means that the Hal-plugin cannot find a value for your the `route_identifier` called `parameter` and because of this it cannot render a self link.

In some of your `metadata_map` configs (nr 1+2) it seems like it should get the value from the resource:
There is a route with route name:

```
'route_name' => 'parent.rest.service',
```

To properly render this route we need a route identifier named `parameter`:

```
'route_identifier_name' => 'parameter',
```

To get the value for this route identifier we need the property named `parameter` from the entity:

```
'entity_identifier_name' => 'parameter',
```

Most likely the entity should have data in an array and that array should hold a key named 'parameter' then it will try to get the value that goes with that key.

---

In another `metadata_map` config you set an array of 'static' route params like this:

```
'route_params' => array('parameter'),
```

This is incomplete, because you set a route parameter array always with a key and a value.
So this should be something like this:

```
'route_params' => array('parameter' => 'my_value'),
```

Where `my_value` can be a string an integer etc.

I hope this insight can help you a bit. I don't seem to totally see where else it could go wrong.

Comment: if the parameter value is dynamic.. I'm at a loss as to how to grab it... in this case it's a user's name

Comment: @Erik If it is the users name and the name of the parameter in the entity is `userName`, you can then set the entity_identifier_name accordingly.

Comment: I renamed it to `parameter` in this question .. for generality purposes.. but I have the correct name in my deployment.

Comment: and here guys, it's how easy is to pass a parameter to this router. Amazing!